# How can I calculate the square of Pauli-Lubanski vector in a rest frame?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, field-theory, tensor-calculus, lie-algebra

recently I've been trying to demonstrate that, $$\textbf{W}^2 = -m^2\textbf{S}^2$$ in a rest frame, with $W_{\mu}$ defined as $$W_{\mu} = \dfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma}M^{\alpha\beta}p^{\gamma}$$ such that $M^{\mu\nu}$ is an operator of the form $$ M^{\mu\nu}=x^{\mu}p^{\nu} - x^{\nu}p^{\mu} + \frac{i}{2}\Sigma^{\mu\nu}$$ and $S^i$ defined as $$S_i = \varepsilon^{ijk}\frac{i}{2}\Sigma^{jk}$$Where $\Sigma^{\mu\nu} = [\beta^{\mu}, \beta^{\nu}]$. I've managed to show that $\textbf{S}^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\Sigma^{ij}\Sigma_{ij}$ but I can't for my life work out the necessary result. Any sort of light towards this is very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Using all your formulas, we find

$$
W_\mu = - \frac{i}{4} m \varepsilon_{0\mu\alpha\beta} \Sigma^{\alpha\beta} .
$$
It is clear that $W_0=0$ and
$$
W_i =  - \frac{i}{4} m \varepsilon_{0ijk} \Sigma^{jk} = \frac{1}{2} S_i . 
$$
It follows that $W^2 = - \frac{1}{4} m^2 S_i^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The only thing that leaves me somewhat confused is that $1/4$ factor becaue the paper I'm reading doesn't really mention anything about it :/ I

Comment: What you're writing is only true if you work in a frame of reference where $p^\mu = (m, \vec{0})$.

Comment: @HansMoleman - The title says "rest frame" so that's obviously the setup I'm assuming.

Comment: @clebbf - I'm using all of your formulas. You should confirm that they are all correct.

Comment: I am sory for the late reply, but why is there a minus sign after squaring the Pauli-Lubanski?